# Android 4.4 and up doesn't provide persistent file path after reboot

Tags: java, android

I'm asking the user to pick an image like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
      intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
      intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
} else
      intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, getResources().getString(R.string.select_image)), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

I'm saving the image Uri like this

```
if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().edit().putString("pic_url", data.getDataString()).apply();
```

And get a bitmap of that image later on like this

```
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(picUrl));
```

The problem is that on API 19+ the uri from my SharedPreferences no longer returns the image that the user picked **after a reboot** (I think there's an exeption thrown at that last line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the `Uri` that you get back from either `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` or `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` will be usable by the activity instance that is called with `onActivityResult()`... and that's it. You can pass the `Uri` around to other components and use `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to pass rights along. But once your process terminates, you are likely to lose access to the content.

With `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, you can use `takePersistableUriPermission()` on `ContentResolver` to try to get durable access to the content identified by the `Uri`.

With `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, you have little choice but to turn this into an "import" operation, using `openInputStream()` on `ContentResolver` and copying the bytes to a file that you control, that you use for your long-term access. The exception would be if the scheme of the `Uri` is `file`, in which case you already have durable access to the content, assuming that the file is on external storage and you have appropriate permissions.

See [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/10/uri-access-lifetime-shorter-than-you-might-think.html) for more.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! But I don't use a `ContentResolver` in my code. May you guide me with this?

Comment: @AlexNewman: "But I don't use a ContentResolver in my code" -- according to your question, you do. See your third code snippet. "May you guide me with this?" -- I do not know what problems you are encountering. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.3/Documents/Durable) illustrates picking an image using either of those actions and taking steps to get durable access to that content. It is covered in detail in [my book](http://commonsware.com/Android/).

Answer (score 1):

Try getting Bitmap using this

```
Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri);
```